# Why are there different timezones between DateTimeZone :: listAbbreviations() and DateTimeZone :: listIdentifiers ()

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I want to get a list of all timezones.

When I use `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()`
I get a list,

And when I use `DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations()` I get a list with different entries.

Each list has values that are not in the second list.
How to get a complete list?

Why is there a difference between the two functions?

Comment: `array_merge` ? If you are letting people choose, it should be from the 'identifiers' list not 'abbreviations'

Comment: Did you see the comments in the docs at https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers and abbreviations are different things, thus you get different lists.

An identifier is bound to a location, so a single time zone (Central Europe Time) will typically relate to several identifiers (Europe/Madrid, Europe/Paris, Europe/Berlin...) and one same identifier can switch time zones (Europe/Madrid is Central European Time, UTC+1, in Winter and Central European Summer Time, UTC+2, in Summer).

An abbreviation is bound to a time zone, so a single abbreviation (CET) only maps to one time zone (Central Europe Time, UTC+1).

If you inspect `DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations())`'s output you'll see that each time zone abbreviation contains a list of its known location identifiers, and they aren't unique because many of them switch time zones due to daylight saving time or political changes.

Answer (score -2):

Are you use the function "timezone_identifiers_list()"?
Return parameter is array,
exp: $timezone_list = timezone_identifiers_list();
print_r($timezone);